# connect to mysql DB using php

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to connect to my DB server using the hostname and the port in the file config.php but still give me error, I won't use the localhost server, the database is in other server.
I get the hostname using : `show variables like '%hostname%'`
and get the port using : `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name =  'port'`

```
define('DB_USER', "test"); 
define('DB_PASSWORD', "test"); 
define('DB_DATABASE', "test"); 
define('DB_SERVER', "My problem is here");
```

someone know what I did wrong?

thank you

Comment: i dont understand. if you can do what sql you post, you are logined into server.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: yes I am logined using the interface of the server but when I try to access to data using php I get failed

Comment: what interface? mysql cli client ?

Comment: i know whats wrong with you. you open mysql cli, and run `netstat -ntp | grep <PORT YOU GET>` to find the server ip

Answer (score 1):

Some hosts, you can't connect to their database from your localhost, but only from their webserver.

Maybe thats your problem ?

Comment: yes Mr Rasmus exactly, so I think I have to megrate my code to the server